# Editing the SASS files for CoreUI within ASPNET Core web site

Tags: asp.net-core, sass, visual-studio-2019, core-ui

We are using Core Admin template, https://coreui.io/ within an ASPNET core website.

We used the very useful template project that brings CoreUI temaplate into an ASPNEt Core project, https://github.com/tolbxela/ASP.NET-Core-UI-Free-Admin-Template

We now need to start editing some key parts of the CoreUI theme. Core UI uses SASS (scss) files, do i neeed to do smething specific to have the SASS files generate CSS when inside Visual Studio\ASPNET Core?

Comment: If you reference it as a static file, it need to be compiled it., if reference it directly, you need to add a library to parse it.

Comment: I've added the WebCompiler addin but I am having loads of issues trying to get the SASS files to compile.